# How can I set a maximum row count for IQueryable

Tags: breeze

I am missing two topics in the Breeze documentation, Security and how to set limits on the data returned.

I don't want someone to delete everything in the database and don't want to return everything.

Should I use OData? with Odata I can set the restrictions I want.

Answer (score 0):

"Security" is a huge, sprawling topic about which there is never enough to say. I hope to chip away at it.

As for limiting the max records, I'd use the `[Queryable]` attribute's `PageSize` option. The `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute inherits this option so you could write your Web API controller method or supporting repository method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable(PageSize=100)] // returns a maximum of 100 orders
public IQueryable Orders() {
   return ContextProvider.Context.Orders;
}
```

You might also be able to limit the results by adding top to the query inside the method.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable Orders() {
   return ContextProvider.Context.Orders.take(100);
}
```

However, certain query conditions may not get through. Try it first.

Comment: I can see that there is some overlap between odata and breeze and I am having a VERY hard time deciding whatever to use EFContextProvider or EntitySetController. I want to be able to use my api with any kind of client

Comment: I think you mean an overlap between Breeze.NET's enhancements to the standard Web API controller and the ASP.NET Web API's OData controller, the EntitySetController. Both are Web API offerings on the server side. Breeze proper is purely client-side. I can't emphasize that difference enough.  Having said that, I'm not sure how you choose. Personally, I feel much more in control with standard Web API controllers which are more easily accessible to a wider range of clients. With the EntitySetController you're pretty much limited to OData clients. IMO.